# onClick function is not fired on any element used as string inside dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know if its a bug or am I doing something wrong.

I have this code, where onClick on anchor does not happen to fire:

```
const DangerousText = props => (
  <div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ // eslint-disable-line
      __html: props.translate(
        props.translationKey,
        {
          link:
            `<a
              href=${props.link}
              onClick="${(event) => { event.preventDefault(); props.history.push(props.link); }}"
            >
              ${props.linkTextTranslationKey ? props.translate(props.linkTextTranslationKey) : ''}
            </a>`,
          ...props.extraVariables,
        },
      ),
    }}
  />
);
```

Similarly if I update the onClick function to immediately invoked function as follows:

```
onClick="${((event) => { event.preventDefault(); props.history.push(props.link); })(event)}"
```

Then this code will fire even when I did not click on anchor.

Comment: Why do you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in the first place?

Comment: Agree, you can turn that code into it's own component if you want.

Comment: @trixn I have a situation, where I don't have any other option.

Comment: @Rodrigo I have tried that too,  but at last I am forced to return a string. So,  I got the same results. Can you please suggest me any example, so that I can take a look at that and find out my mistake.

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is used to set contents of an element to an HTML string, not react code, and it won't be able to access the scope of the component it's "inside" of.

Comment: @Vishal "I have a situation, where I don't have any other option." Well the valid use cases for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML ` are quite rare and I don't see anything that makes me believe this requires to use it. Might be the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/364724). I don't see a simple solution for that. But please provide some more context about **why** you think that you have no other choice. Maybe another solution that does not involve `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is a lot simpler.

Comment: @Vishal You mention that you're *forced to return a string*. For what I see you're using a custom `<a>` tag to run some react router code `props.history.push(props.link);`. Why you must return a string?. Anyway this is a simplified scenario of a component doing something similar to your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dqrvd5?file=index.js